# CheckBox Value dosent show up When Modelstate is not valid on RegisterForm

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, checkboxlist

i have a signup view with checkBoxOption

```
 <div class="form-group">
                @Html.Label("Whice Console You Play?")
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.ConsolesCheckBoxList.Count; i++)
                     {

                      @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model.ConsolesCheckBoxList[i].IsChecked)
                      @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.ConsolesCheckBoxList[i].ConsoleId)
                      @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.ConsolesCheckBoxList[i].ConsoleName)


                    }
            </div>
```

when one of the input in this form not good or not been insert, there are the ValidationMessageFor and the view is redisplay, after that the value of the checkbox are been gone, why that?

this is the code for controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register([Bind(Exclude = "UserPhoto")]CommenModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // To convert the user uploaded Photo as Byte Array before save to DB
            byte[] imageData = null;
            if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                HttpPostedFileBase poImgFile = Request.Files["UserPhoto"];

                using (var binary = new BinaryReader(poImgFile.InputStream))
                {
                    imageData = binary.ReadBytes(poImgFile.ContentLength);
                }
            }




            var user = new ApplicationUser
            {
                UserName = model.registerViewModel.Email,
                Email = model.registerViewModel.Email,
                Phone = model.registerViewModel.Phone

            };



            user.UserPhoto = imageData;
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.registerViewModel.Password);

            //after the user create, we will use the id and add the id to the userAddress table include
            // Address, langitud and latitude.
            using (ApplicationDbContext dbo = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                var currentUserId = user.Id;
                var pasinfo = dbo.userAddress.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Userid == currentUserId);

                if (pasinfo == null)
                {
                    pasinfo = dbo.userAddress.Create();
                    pasinfo.Userid = currentUserId;
                    dbo.userAddress.Add(pasinfo);
                }
                pasinfo.Address = model.useraddress.Address;
                pasinfo.latitude = model.useraddress.latitude;
                pasinfo.longitude = model.useraddress.longitude;
                dbo.SaveChanges();

                // now we used foreach loop to check which box is set to true on the view, and if the box set to true
                // we take the id of the boxname and save it in conoleid.
                foreach (var item in model.ConsolesCheckBoxList.Where(x => x.IsChecked).Select(x => x.ConsoleId))
                {
                    var consoleid = item;
                    //here we create a new consoleuserInfo to insert data.
                    var consoleUserInfo = new ConsoleUserInfo
                    {
                        //we insert the id of user, and the consoleid of the checkbox how been marked.
                        Userid = currentUserId,
                        ConsoleId = consoleid


                    };
                    dbo.consoleUserInfo.Add(consoleUserInfo);


                }
                dbo.SaveChanges();

            }


            if (result.Succeeded)
            {

                // await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);


                // Send an email with this link
                 string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                 var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                 await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

and this is my get view on my controller:

```
 // GET: /Account/Register
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Register()

    {
        //using database
        using (ApplicationDbContext dbo = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            //data will save list of the consoleCheckBoxItem
            var data = dbo.consolesCheckBox.ToList();
            // because the view is request a common model, we will create new one
            CommenModel a = new CommenModel();
            a.ConsolesCheckBoxList = data;
            //  we will need to return common model, that way we will returen a


            return View(a);

        }
    }
```